# How to highlight text, values from table saved when edit button is selected?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I used the search function and I've seen a lot of topic about "how to highlight a text " but I couldn't find a way to implement it in my asp.net website project.

> I'm using a gridview and for search function I'm using this :

```
 SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "select * from TableName where Name like '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%' or SecName like '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%'";
         SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
```

How can I do it ? I would like someone to explain step by step , I need to do this for tomorrow and I'm not very advanced. ty

Also ,

When a user is selecting the button edit from gridview I want to save all data from fields in some variables and when he clicks update . a textbox will have a new line with the last values before editing and the new values like this :

```
ID: number , Value from Name "value" was edited with "new value " , SecName = the current value. and so on.
```

Thank you ,
  bye

Comment: would someone help me please?

Comment: To get help, I think we need to work on formatting your question to be more understandable. What, exactly, are you highlighting? You've posted code related to grid databinding, but that just sets the results for the grid. What text is highlighted on the resulting page? Your solution is likely going to involve some CSS, but I'm not sure yet of what the question is to answer.